# Delimited arguments and using a macro inside of itself

Tags: macros, tex-core, plain-tex, delimiters

I wanted to play with delimiter sizing without using the `\delimiterfactor`, `-shortfall`, etc. and made the following:

```
\newdimen\bigdim  \bigdim  = 1.9743ex
\newdimen\Bigdim  \Bigdim  = 2.671ex
\newdimen\biggdim \biggdim = 3.3678ex
\newdimen\Biggdim \Biggdim = 4.0646ex

\def\fence#1#2#3{
  \setbox0\hbox{$\displaystyle #3$}
  \ifdim\ht0 < .9\bigdim #1\box0 #2\else
  \ifdim\ht0 < .9\Bigdim \bigl#1\box0\bigr#2\else
  \ifdim\ht0 < .9\biggdim \Bigl#1\box0\Bigr#2\else
  \ifdim\ht0 < .9\Biggdim \biggl#1\box0\biggr#2\else
  \ifdim\ht0 < .9\Biggdim \Biggl#1\box0\Biggr#2\else
  \left#1\box0\right#2
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}

\def\args(#1){\fence(){#1}}

$$
  \args(bar\args(baz))
$$

\bye
```

(before you push that comment-button, I know there should be `\mathsurround=0pt` and such in there, I just wanted to keep this simple) but this results in an error saying the argument of `\args` has an extra `}`.

I thought it would have something to do with macro argument delimiters, so made a quick test:

```
\def\foo(#1){(#1)}
\foo(bar\foo(baz))
\bye
```

but that seemed to work just fine.  Now I don't know what else could be the issue. Note that if there isn't an `\args` inside of `\args`, it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have

```
\args(bar\args(baz))
```

so the argument to the outer `\args` is

```
 bar\args(baz
```

as it stops at the first `)`

you want

```
 \args({bar\args(baz)})
```

in the `\foo` example, the arguments are interpreted the same way, but it accidentally works.

for the outer `\foo` `'#1` is

```
bar\foo(baz
```

so that expands to

```
(bar\foo(baz)
```

then the inner `\foo` expands to

```
 (baz)
```

and finally the `)` which was never used as a macro delimiter is typeset.

Comment: So the outer one is expanded before the inner one? That's... gross.

Comment: Well how come it works with the `\foo` then?

Comment: @morbusg not expanded, scanned, the arguments are scanned _before_ the macro expands, I'll step through the foo example in a minute

Comment: @morbusg If you want to do delimiter matching such a case you've got to work hard: it's doable but tedious (see `xparse` for an example which does work at the cost of a lot of effort).

Comment: @morbusg see updated answer

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this. I mean, I understand what the issue is, but I don't understand how to sidestep it. Any way I could make it “accidentally work” with the `\args` without explicitly bracing the arguments when using the macro? :)

Comment: @morbusg not really TeX only has one kind of matching (catcode 1 and 2 so normally { and }) if you delimit an argument as `(#1)` it will take everything up to the first `)` as `#1` without matching anything other than `{}`. You see same in latex's `[]` delimited optional arguments. as Joseph said xparse will match `()` if you want but it does it by reading token by token and matching braces "by hand"

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks, but the L3 syntax is a bit too alien for me to follow. I'll just take your word for it being hard and tedious. :)

Comment: @morbusg I'll see if I can write a demo using the same algorithm and primitives: may take a little while!

Comment: Now let's see. What happens with `\args(bar\args(baz))`? I guess the height satisfies condition 1, so the first `\args` should expand to `\bigl(bar\args(baz\bigr))`, then the internal `\args` is expanded, and should get to `\bigl(bar\bigl(baz\bigr)\bigr)`, but the `\bigr)` that seems to close the internal `\args` is in fact part of its argument. So we guess the problem somehow comes from the sizing, which prevents the first `)` to be taken as the closing of the internal `\args`'s argument as happens with the `\foo`. In all that, I don't quite see how we get an `Extra }`. Let's test this with …

Comment: … a `\foo` with sizing. Result: `Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again>    \mathclose    l.5 $$\foo(bar\foo(baz)    )$$`, error detected between the two `)`s.

Comment: @MickG no there is no height to satisfy any condition. The outer `\args` tries to set its argument in a box so it evaluates `\hbox{$\displaystyle bar\args(baz$}` and if that box was set its height would be measured but the inner `\args` fails with a runaway argument error as it has no `)`

Comment: @JosephWright Any news on that “small demo”?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\ensurebalanced` macro for another types of parens by the following way:

```
\def\macro(#1){\ensurebalanced()\macroA{#1}}
\def\macroA#1{the "#1" is balanced here in () meaning}

\macro(abc(de(f))g(hi)) % prints: the "abc(de(f))g(hi)" is balanced here in () meaning.
```

Or your example:

```
\def\args(#1){\ensurebalanced(){\fence()}{#1}}
```

My macro `\ensurebalanced` looks like this:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\ensurebalanced#1#2#3#4{%
   \isbalanced#1#2{#4}\iftrue #3{#4}%
   \else
      \def\ensurebalancedA##1##2#2{%
         \isbalanced#1#2{##1#2##2}\iftrue #3{##1#2##2}%
         \else \def\next{\ensurebalancedA{##1#2##2}}\expandafter\next\fi
      }%
      \def\next{\ensurebalancedA{#4}}\expandafter\next\fi
}
\def\isbalanced#1#2#3\iftrue{\tmpnum=0 \isbalancedA#1#2#3\isbalanced}
\def\isbalancedA#1#2#3{%
    \ifx\isbalanced#3\def\next{\csname ifnum\endcsname\tmpnum=0 }%
    \else \def\next{\isbalancedA#1#2}%
          \ifx#3#1\advance\tmpnum by1\fi
          \ifx#3#2\advance\tmpnum by-1\fi
    \fi \next
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! `:-)`. I guess one needs a `\newcount\tmpnum` to go with it.

Comment: @morbusg Thanks. I have `\tmpnum` declared by default. Thus I forgot it. I corrected the code.