# Arguments possibly delimited by \bgroup and \egroup

Tags: tex-core, expansion, grouping

I still don't see (and haven't thought about) pros and cons of making available the arguments as `\foo{…}` or `\foo\bgroup …\egroup` (or even unbalanced, `\bgroup …}` and `{…\egroup`). But I'm curious about enabling it for certain commands (in a way that, for instance, you could create environments from commands).

How can we create a macro like

```
\def\foo#1{…}
```

that does accept

```
\foo\bgroup …\egroup
```

Another option I thought about is a command like

```
\delimitedbybegroup{<pre code>}<argument delimited by braces or \bgroup and \egroup>
```

So one could say `\delimitedbybegroup\emph{Some text}` or `\delimitedbybegroup\emph\bgroup Some text\egroup` both of them giving `\emph{Some text}`.

A more advanced one, for instance, might be

```
\delimitedbybegroup{\def\foo#1#2}\bgroup Something with #1 and #2\egroup
```

---

In any case any thoughts about why and why not are useful this kind of commands would be welcome.

And, in a similar way… how are (usually) handled commands that do look for a “closing” token, if the token is not visible. Like

```
\def\foo{\delimiter}
\def\baz#1\delimiter{…#1…}
\baz some code \foo{} and some more here that should be outside the argument of \string\baz.
```

Comment: An idea could be using a token register, but a `<general text>` *must* end with an explicit brace, not `\egroup`. For font changing or box making commands it is actually easy, but delimiting an argument of a general macro either by `\egroup` or `}`₁ is difficult, if ever possible. And I'm really dubious about its usefulness.

Comment: since it's easier to type `{]` than `\bgroup\egroup` and _much_ easier and more robust to define commands using that form why would you want to do this? your question gives no indication of any possible reason or potential benefit.

Comment: As far as I know, macros defined with `\def`, or similar defining commands, behave in a very different way from native commands; the latter accept the balanced braces as well as the balanced `\bgroup` and `\egroup` pairs, even if these implicit braces are used inside different macros, for example the opening and the closing macros of an environment. Parsing macros for finding their arguments is not the same as processing their arguments by native commands.

Comment: Only primitives that have `{<balanced text>}` as argument accept `\bgroup` or `\egroup` in place of `{` or `}` (`\hbox`, for instance). Primitives that have `<general text>` as argument, only accept `\bgroup` as a replacement of `{`, but require `}` at the end (`\uppercase`, for instance). Some primitives (the `\def` family) have an argument that *must* be delimited by explicit braces.

Comment: @egreg I'm also dubious about its usefulness, but I'm curiuous about *why* do this option exist for some commands, and *if* it is possible to create a command that accepts such king of arguments (the same as `\hbox`).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Curiosity. And also what reason saw Knuth to offer such possibility, and, since I've seen many, many times `\hbox\bgroup` … `\egroup`, I think it *might* be useful (although it's true that we have survived all these years without it :D).

Comment: That's the point: Knuth _didn't_ offer the possibility in TeX (so any faking of the syntax in the macro layer is going to be very fragile) the syntax for `\hbox` is completely different and closer to _grouping_ than to delimiting arguments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, then having such *grouping* in an argument is enough. By the way, to the last part, I know the definition of `|…verbatim#1\end{verbatim}[…]` which is IMO quite fragile, and anything better than that would be great. For instance, something that works like `a_\mathrm{min}` but in a user created command would be welcome.

Comment: `a_\mathrm{min}` is just such horrible markup (and greatly limits what you can do with the`^` and `_` syntax:-) So many uses (for language shortcuts or html generation or ...) want to overload `_` and `^` with active characters with macro definitions and it's not possible to recreate that syntax sensibly  using a macro. If users used the documented `a_{\mathrm{min}}` form, it would be trivial to overload `_`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't mean I want that (in fact, since two months ago, I use active `^` and `_` to adjust them to my needs), it was just an example of what the question asks.

Comment: well basically the answer is as below and in egreg's comment to that answer, you can't do this at the macro layer, sorry:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In that case let's pray for some wipet's sorcery :P

Comment: The task can be solved similar as `\Open` `\Close` macro from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196071/macro-to-close-all-open-environments-groups-and-argument-delimiters . But I'am not sure the serviceability of this. These two types of separators will be used only for parameter scanning (without total expandning). The point of these two separators in primitives are that these separators are scanned during total expansion (for example `\egroup` is in a macro expanded later). For example `a_\mathrm{min}` does `a_\bgroup something\egroup` after expansion, no during parameter scanning.

Comment: @wipet It was more like if there was a way of bringing that behaviour from primitives to user defined macros, rather than hack a preprocessor. By the way, the second subquestion is still vague, although I think the answer is a clear no (expanding the arguments until it finds a the delimiter of the macro —which, in my example, is inside another macro—).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question gives me a sense if it is read from its end: *give
the possibility of creating a macro which expands its parameter during
parameter scanning*. Then the variants `}` or `\egroup` as a delimiter of the
parameter is serviceable.

I've created the `\eparam` macro with this syntax:

```
\def\mymacro #1{the #1 parameter is declared as undelimited}
...
\eparam\mymacro parameter-text
```

The `parameter-text` is equal to `real-parameter-text` enclosed by braces or
by another control sequences declared by `\eparamopen` and `\eparamclose`.
Example:

```
\eparamopen\start  \eparamclose\stop
\eparam\mymacro {real-parameter-text}
\eparam\mymacro \start real-parameter-text\stop
\eparam\mymacro \start real-parameter-text}
\eparam\mymacro {real-parameter-text\stop
```

The main point of the `\eparam` is that it prepares an **Expanded Parameter**.
The `real-parameter-text` is expanded during parameter scanning like
by `\edef`. This means that all expandable primitives and macros are
expanded during the parameter is read. Unexpandable primitives do nothing
in this time (like `\edef`) so you can do reassigmnent of registers/macros
inside this parameter but without any effect for parameter scaninng.
This is main difference between this case and the `\hbox {...}` primitive
syntax.

There is one little difference between `\edef` and parameter scanning:
undefined control sequences do nothing (like unexpandable primitives)
during parameter scanning. The error can be occur only when the parameter is
used (no during parameter scanning).

The separator declared by `\eparamclose` can be hidden in a macro. Example:

```
\def\x{-text\stop}
\eparam\mymacro {real-parameter\x
```

The first open brace or delimiter given by `\eparamopen` is optional. I.e.
you can omit it:

```
\eparam\mymacro real-parameter-text\stop
```

The parameter is always balanced by braces. This means that the delimiter declared by `\eparamclose` does no effect inside inner braces pair (like normal
parameter scanning):

```
\eparam \start text{inside \stop braces}text\stop
% the parameter is: "text{inside \stop braces}text"
```

The implementation (or wipet's sorcery :) and little tests follow.

```
\def\tmp{% all expandable primitives (only from classical TeX, you can add others):
  \botmark \csname \else \endcsname \endinput \expandafter \fi \firstmark \fontname
  \if \ifcase \ifcat \ifdim \ifeof \iffalse \ifhbox \ifhmode \ifinner       
  \ifmmode \ifnum \ifodd \iftrue \ifvbox \ifvmode \ifvoid \ifx
  \input \jobname \meaning \noexpand \number \or \romannumeral
  \splitbotmark \splitfirstmark \string \the \topmark
}
\def\skipmm#1->{}  \def\showmm#1->{#1}
\edef\textmm{\expandafter\showmm\meaning\empty}
\edef\expandprimitives{\expandafter\skipmm\meaning\tmp}

\def\isinlist#1#2#3{% from opmac.tex
   \def\tmp##1#2##2\end{\def\tmp{##2}%
   \ifx\tmp\empty \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname \else
                  \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname \fi}% end of \def\tmp
   \expandafter\tmp#1\endlistsep#2\end
}
\def\isexpanded#1#2{% \isexpanded X\iftrue the X is expandable primitive or macro\fi
   \edef\tmpb{\meaning#1\space}%
   \expandafter\isinlist\expandafter\tmpb\expandafter{\textmm}%
   \iftrue \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname\else
      \def\nexxt{\expandafter\isinlist\expandafter\expandprimitives\expandafter{\tmpb}.}%
      \expandafter\nexxt\fi
}
\def\eparamopen#1{\def\eparamopenA{\let#1=\eparamopenA}}
\def\eparamclose#1{\def\eparamcloseA{\let#1=\eparamcloseA}}

\newtoks\eparamT
\def\eparam#1{\begingroup
  \toks0={#1}\let\bgroup=\relax \let\egroup=\relax
  \let\ifIamInGroup=\iffalse
  \ifx\eparamopenA\undefined \def\eparamopenA{^\eparam^}\else \eparamopenA\fi
  \ifx\eparamcloseA\undefined \def\eparamcloseA{^\eparam^}\else \eparamcloseA\fi
  \eparamT={}\eparamA
}
\def\eparamA{\futurelet\tmpc\eparamB}
\def\eparamB{\let\next=\eparamD
   \isexpanded\tmpc\iftrue \def\next{\expandafter\eparamA}\fi
   \ifx\tmpc\bgroupOri \let\next=\eparamC \let\nexxt=\eparamD \fi  
   \ifx\tmpc\eparamopenA  \let\next=\eparamC \let\nexxt=\eparamD \fi
   \next
}
\def\eparamC{\afterassignment\nexxt \let\next= }
\def\eparamD{\futurelet\tmpc\eparamE}
\def\eparamE{\let\next=\eparamN
   \isexpanded\tmpc\iftrue \def\next{\expandafter\eparamD}\fi
   \ifx\tmpc\spacetoken \let\next=\eparamC \let\nexxt=\eparamD \eparamX{ }\fi
   \ifx\tmpc\eparamcloseA \ifIamInGroup \let\next=\eparamN
                          \else \let\next=\eparamC \let\nexxt=\eparamF \fi\fi
   \ifx\tmpc\egroupOri \let\next=\eparamC \let\nexxt=\eparamF \fi
   \ifx\tmpc\bgroupOri \let\next=\eparamC \let\nexxt=\eparamG \fi
   \next
}
\def\eparamN#1{\eparamX#1\eparamD}
\def\eparamG{\begingroup \let\ifIamInGroup=\iftrue \eparamT={}\eparamD}
\def\eparamF{\ifIamInGroup \let\next=\eparamY \else \let\next=\eparamZ \fi \next}
\long\def\eparamX#1{\eparamT\expandafter{\the\eparamT#1}}
\def\eparamY{\expandafter\endgroup
   \expandafter\eparamT\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\eparamT\expandafter{\the\eparamT}}%
   \eparamD
}
\def\eparamZ{\expandafter\endgroup\the\toks0\expandafter{\the\eparamT}}

\let\bgroupOri=\bgroup
\let\egroupOri=\egroup
\def\tmp/{\let\spacetoken= }\tmp/ %

\def\macro#1{\toks0={#1}\message{the parameter is "\the\toks0"}}

\eparam\macro {abc}  % the parameter is "abc"

\def\x{ww}
\eparam\macro {ab\x c}          % the parameter is "abwwc"
\eparam\macro {ab\the\pageno c} % the parameter is "ab1c"
\eparam\macro {ab\ifx\x\x true\else false\fi c}        % the parameter is "abtruec"
\eparam\macro {ab\ifnum\folio=1 true\else false\fi c}  % the parameter is "abtruec"
\eparam\macro {ab\ifcase\pageno oo\or one\or two\fi c} % the parameter is "abonec"

\eparamopen\start \eparamclose\stop

\eparam\macro {abc\stop        % the parameter is "abc"
\eparam\macro \start abc\stop  % the parameter is "abc"
\eparam\macro \start abc}      % the parameter is "abc"

\eparam\macro abc}     % the parameter is "abc"
\eparam\macro abc\stop % the parameter is "abc"

\eparam\macro \start abc{uf\stop fu}ee\stop  % the parameter is "abc{uf\stop fu}ee"

\def\y{end\stop}

\eparam\macro {a\x\y   % the parameter is "awwend"

\end
```

**Edit:** I did do a small modification of the code in order to solve the last demand from the question:

```
\eparamopen\bgroup \eparamclose\egroup
\eparam {\def\foo#1#2}\bgroup Something with #1 and #2\egroup
```

acts like `\edef\foo#1#2{Something with #1 and #2}`.

If you need to deactivate the expansion process (i.e. you need to do `\def`, no `\edef`) then you can declare

```
\def\isexpanded#1#2{\iffalse}
```

Of course, the delimiter declared by `\eparamclose` cannot be found in nested macro in such case.

Comment: Well, this is clearly great. Just one thing that might come in handy, although I don't know if it is easy: is there an easy way to control expansion of macros (I mean, like a list of those which should not expand, where you could add macros at wish).

Comment: @Manuel IMHO, it is simple. User can `\def\macrolist{\a \b \othermacro}` as a list of noexpanded macros. Then you can insert `\expandafter\settorelax\macrolist\end` to the `\eparam` macro (after `\begingroup`) and finally you need to define `\settorelax` as following: `\def\settorelax#1{\ifx#1\end \else \let#1=\relax \expandafter\settorelax\fi}`.

Comment: Well, this is not what the question asks. You don't define `\macro` with an argument delimited by either `{}` or `\bgroup\egroup`, but `\eparam`.

Comment: @egreg This is more like the answer to my `\delimitedbybegroup` macro. The answer to that seems to be *it's not possible to bring that behaviour from primitives to a user defined command* (unless you use hacks like these), isn't it?

Comment: @Manuel That's what I wrote in my answer, isn't it? *If* a primitive accepts `\bgroup` and `\egroup` you can do by having the primitive last in the definition of the macro you want. Otherwise you simply can't. This is clever code, but I guess you wouldn't try having `\textbf` in the “argument”; of course you can add it to the list of unexpanded macros: how long would this list be?

Comment: @egreg You are not right (as usually:-). User can declare `\eparamopen\bgroup` `\eparamclose\egroup` and define `\def\macro#1{...}` `\def\Macro{\eparam\macro}` and use `\Macro{text}` or `\Macro\bgroup text}` or `\Macro{text\egroup` or `\Macro\bgroup text\egroup`.

Comment: @egreg Well, here you can do that without needing a primitive (like `\hbox`) that acts like that.

Comment: There is another iteresting extension of this code. We can use *controlled expansion + assignment*. User can declare which type of assigment (`\let`, `\count...=` etc.) would be done during parameter scanning and the expansion plus choosen assignments are done at this time. I will not modify the code in this way because this was not the subject of the question.

Answer (score 10):

The syntax rules of TeX allow for certain primitives to have an “argument” delimited by `\bgroup` or `\egroup`. The main examples are

> `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\vtop`, `\vcenter`, `\halign` and `\noalign`.

This is the basis where, for instance, `\halign` LaTeX builds `tabular` on: with `\begin{tabular}{<arg>}` the argument is transformed into a suitable preamble for `\halign` and then, besides other things irrelevant for this discussion, TeX executes

```
\leavevmode$\vcenter\bgroup\halign\bgroup<built preamble>\cr
```

and, when `\end{tabular}` is found,

```
\crcr\egroup\egroup$
```

is performed. The `\vcenter` can be `\vbox` or `\vtop` depending on the option given to `tabular`. Of course, this possibility is exploited also in `lrbox`.

Other primitive commands accept an argument in the form of a `<general text>` and the TeXbook describes this as

```
<filler>{<balanced text><right brace>
```

where `<filler>` is an arbitrary sequence of `\relax` and space tokens, `{` means an **implicit or explicit token with category code 1** (so either `{` or `\bgroup`) and `<right brace>` means **an explicit character token of category code 1**.

Examples of primitives with this are `\uppercase`, `\message`, `\write` and `\mark`, besides assignments to token registers:

```
<token variable><equals><general text>
```

So you *can't* define a macro based on `\uppercase` whose argument is delimited by `\egroup`, but you can do it with `\hbox`.

Worse, for your plan, is the fact that the replacement text in a macro definition ***must*** be delimited by explicit character tokens of categories 1 and 2 respectively.

Note that there is a rule of thumb for knowing which primitives accept `\egroup` as final delimiter: those where the argument is enclosed in an implicit group (with a quirk about `\halign` because `\tabskip` assignments will be performed outside this implicit group). This is the case also for the primitive actions of `_` and `^`, by the way.

It's impossible to define a general macro whose argument can be delimited by `}` or `\egroup`. An apparent argument can, provided the replacement text ends with a primitive accepting `\egroup` in the first place; `\aftergroup` trickery can then be used for completing the task. Just to make a silly example, here's an implementation of `\vfbox` that takes a named color as optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vfbox}[1][black]{%
  \def\vfbox@color{#1}%
  \setbox\vfbox@box=\hbox\bgroup
  \aftergroup\vfbox@do
  \let\next=
}

\newcommand{\vfbox@do}{%
  \begingroup
  \color{\vfbox@color}%
  \fbox{\box\vfbox@box}%
  \endgroup
}

\newbox\vfbox@box
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\vfbox\bgroup abc\egroup

\vfbox{abc\egroup

\vfbox[blue]\bgroup abc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you can't do it with `\uppercase` (besides its limitation).

Comment: I didn't accept this answer, it was accepted itself when upvoted (may be some of the remaining problems from yesterday?).

Comment: Ok, now it has disappeared.

Comment: It seems so :-)

Comment: Small question: how does `environ` package works? Is it somehow related? How does it do to grab the “argument” ending in `\end{<environ>}`? Or may be it has nothing to do?

Comment: @Manuel Yes, an environment defined with `\NewEnviron` grabs the argument delimited by `\end{<name>}`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has created an argument, and some users here think it's not straightforward nor useful. However, as I *said* in the question, it was curiosity, so wipet's solution does work.

However, I tend to understand much more easier expl3 code rather than the TeX primitives alone (for instance, many macros used here were found just by logic, searching in the documentation for what I thought would be a correct name for the command I was looking for, and I found them).

This is more or less wipet's answer, but trying to bring a little clarity through expl3. I *did* change some things, so may be it doesn't work; it just *seems to work* with the examples given.

I did not try at all to find better names for the functions (see my lazyness even in using `@@` in the name of the functions to avoid “inventing” something, or using `:w` everywhere to avoid thinking). I did not find a way of using only token lists rather than the deprecated toks (although I tried, I'm quite unexperienced here). I might even misused expl3 due to my abscence of knowledge. So, *anything* is welcome.

Here it is.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,dvipsnames,x11names]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[mathlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor,etoolbox,multicol}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% From l3toks (begin)

\cs_new_protected:Npn \toks_new:N #1
  { \__chk_if_free_cs:N #1 \newtoks #1 }
\toks_new:N \c_empty_toks
\cs_new_eq:NN \toks_use:N \tex_the:D
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \toks_set_eq:NN #1 #2 { #1 = #2 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toks_set:Nn #1 #2 { #1 =               { #2 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toks_set:No #1 #2 { #1 = \exp_after:wN { #2 } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toks_gset:Nn { \tex_global:D \toks_set:Nn }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toks_gset:No { \tex_global:D \toks_set:No }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \toks_clear:N #1
  { \toks_set_eq:NN #1 \c_empty_toks }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \toks_put_right:Nn #1 #2
  { #1 = \exp_after:wN { \toks_use:N #1 #2 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \toks_set:Nn  { Nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \toks_gset:Nn { Nx }
\toks_new:N \g_tmpa_toks

% (end) % check if correct and drop this and use _tl if possible

\NewDocumentCommand \egrabparameter { }
  {
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_@@_macro_noexpand_tl \g_@@_macros_noexpand_tl
    \bool_set_true:N \l_@@_expand_bool
    \@@_grabparameter:nw
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \grabparameter { }
  {
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l_@@_macro_noexpand_tl \g_@@_macros_noexpand_tl
    \bool_set_false:N \l_@@_expand_bool
    \@@_grabparameter:nw
  }

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_set_begindelim:N #1
  { \cs_set:Npn \@@_begin_delim: { \cs_set_eq:NN #1 \@@_begin_delim: } }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_set_enddelim:N #1
  { \cs_set:Npn \@@_end_delim: {\cs_set_eq:NN #1 \@@_end_delim: } }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_set_to_relax:N #1
  { \cs_set_eq:NN #1 \scan_stop: }

\toks_new:N \l_@@_parameter_toks
\toks_new:N \l_@@_preamble_toks
\bool_new:N \l_@@_ingroup_bool
\bool_new:N \l_@@_expand_bool
\tl_new:N \g_@@_macros_noexpand_tl
\tl_new:N \l_@@_macros_noexpand_tl
\tl_new:N \l_@@_parameter_tl
\tl_new:N \l_@@_preamble_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_grabparameter:nw #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_map_function:NN \g_@@_macros_noexpand_tl \@@_set_to_relax:N
      \toks_set:Nn \l_@@_preamble_toks { #1 }
      \cs_set_eq:NN \bgroup \scan_stop:
      \cs_set_eq:NN \egroup \scan_stop:
      \bool_set_false:N \l_@@_ingroup_bool
      \bool_if:NF \l_@@_expand_bool
        { \cs_set_eq:NN \token_if_expandable:NT \use_none:nn }
      \cs_if_exist:NTF \@@_begin_delim: 
        { \@@_begin_delim: }
        { \cs_set:Npn \@@_begin_delim: { ^\eparam^ } }
      \cs_if_exist:NTF \@@_end_delim: 
        { \@@_end_delim: }
        { \cs_set:Npn \@@_end_delim: { ^\eparam^ } }
      \toks_clear:N \l_@@_parameter_toks
      \@@_aux_A:w
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_A:w { \peek_after:Nw \@@_aux_B:w }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_B:w 
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_D:w
    \token_if_expandable:NT \l_peek_token
      { \cs_set:Npn \__tmpa_cs:w { \exp_after:wN \@@_aux_A:w } }
    \token_if_group_begin:NT \l_peek_token
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_C:w 
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpb_cs:w \@@_aux_D:w
      }
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token \@@_begin_delim:
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_C:w
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpb_cs:w \@@_aux_D:w
      }
    \__tmpa_cs:w
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_C:w 
  {
    \tex_afterassignment:D \__tmpb_cs:w
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_D:w { \peek_after:Nw \@@_aux_E:w }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_E:w
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_N:w 
    \token_if_expandable:NT \l_peek_token 
      { \cs_set:Npn \__tmpa_cs:w { \exp_after:wN \@@_aux_D:w } }
    \token_if_space:NT \l_peek_token
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_C:w
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpb_cs:w \@@_aux_D:w 
        \@@_aux_X:w { ~ }
      }
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token \@@_end_delim:
      {
        \bool_if:NTF \l_@@_ingroup_bool
          { \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_N:w }
          {
            \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_C:w
            \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpb_cs:w \@@_aux_F:w
          }
      }
    \token_if_group_end:NT \l_peek_token
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_C:w
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpb_cs:w \@@_aux_F:w
      }
    \token_if_group_begin:NT \l_peek_token
      {
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_C:w
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpb_cs:w \@@_aux_G:w
      }
    \__tmpa_cs:w 
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_aux_N:w #1 { \@@_aux_X:w #1 \@@_aux_D:w }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_G:w
  {
    \group_begin:
      \bool_set_true:N \l_@@_ingroup_bool
      \toks_clear:N \l_@@_parameter_toks
      \@@_aux_D:w
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_F:w
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_@@_ingroup_bool
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_Y:w }
      { \cs_set_eq:NN \__tmpa_cs:w \@@_aux_Z:w }
    \__tmpa_cs:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_aux_X:w #1
  {
    \toks_put_right:Nn \l_@@_parameter_toks { #1 }
  }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_Y:w
  {
%   \exp_after:wN \group_end: % -
%   \exp_after:wN \l_@@_parameter_toks % -
%   \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN % -
%   \exp_after:wN { % -
%   \exp_after:wN \toks_use:N % -
%   \exp_after:wN \l_@@_parameter_toks % -
%   \exp_after:wN { % -
%     \toks_use:N \l_@@_parameter_toks } } % -
      \toks_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_toks { \toks_use:N \l_@@_parameter_toks } % +
    \group_end: % +
    \toks_set:Nx \l_@@_parameter_toks % +
      { \toks_use:N \l_@@_parameter_toks { \toks_use:N \g_tmpa_toks } } % +
    \@@_aux_D:w
  }
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \@@_aux_Z:w
  {
%   \exp_after:wN \group_end: % -
%     \toks_use:N \toks0 % -
%%  \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN % +
%%  \exp_after:wN \group_end: % +
%%  \exp_after:wN \toks_use:N % +
%%  \exp_after:wN \l_@@_preamble_toks % +
%%  \exp_after:wN {
%%    \toks_use:N \l_@@_parameter_toks }
      \tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl
        { \toks_use:N \l_@@_preamble_toks { \toks_use:N \l_@@_parameter_toks } }
    \group_end:
    \g_tmpa_tl
  }

\@@_set_begindelim:N \bgroup
\@@_set_enddelim:N   \egroup
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_@@_macros_noexpand_tl { }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{multicols}{3}\KOMAoptions{parskip=never}\parindent=0pt

\def\tmp#1{[{#1}]}
\def\macro{\grabparameter\tmp}
\def\emacro{\egrabparameter\tmp}%

\macro\bgroup abc \textit{\color{Tomato3} foo} no\egroup

\macro{real-parameter-text}\par
\macro\bgroup real-parameter-text\egroup\par
\macro\bgroup real-parameter-text}\par
\macro{real-parameter-text\egroup\par
\macro{abc}
\def\x{ww}\par
\emacro{ab\x c}\par
\emacro{ab\thepage c}\par
\emacro{ab\ifx\x\x true\else false\fi c}\par
\emacro{ab\ifnum\value{page}=1 true\else false\fi c}\par
\emacro{ab\ifcase\value{page} oo\or one\or two\fi c}\par
\emacro{abc\egroup\par
\emacro\bgroup abc\egroup\par
\emacro\bgroup abc}\par
\emacro abc}\par
\emacro abc\egroup\par
\emacro\bgroup abc{\noexpand\color{red}uf\string^ fu}ee\egroup

\end{multicols}\unskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\newenvironment{texttolowercase}{\egrabparameter\lowercase\bgroup}{\egroup}

\begin{texttolowercase}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{texttolowercase}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I am happy that somebody did understand my code at this level of complexity without comments in the code. And it was extensive work.

Comment: There is a little bug: spaces are converted to `\c_space_token`, no real space. It doesn't matter for printing but it woul be problem when scanning parameter separated by space.

Comment: I still don't understand the usefulness of expl3. We can do comparison with the approach with primitives. Manuel said that expl3 spares the coding of `\isexpanded` because it is already done. The `\isexpanded` is implemented on 17 lines in plain TeX code and whole stuff (including `\isexpanded`) is implemented on 63 lines (2.9kB) without loading any external file. The expl3 code is on 160 lines (6kB). All these lines have to read the human if he/she needs to understand. This is less comfort. And five external lines are loaded with next 19482 lines of code. Where is added value in use?

Comment: That in your code I need more than two or three seconds to understand where I am, and in expl3 just one. Apart from that I *do* like verbose names. I guess it's just the same as everywhere: “young people” tend to adapt better to new things basically because they were never used to the “old things”. And yes, it's longer (and loads tons of lines) but does it matter? I mean… the hard drives nowadays have tons of gigabytes, and loading those lines are negligible with current processors.

Comment: If you are doing this as an exercise in `expl3` coding, I'd suggest replacing all of the `toks` stuff with the appropriate `tl` functions :-)

Comment: @JosephWright It doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: @Manuel You are doing something wrong :-) As always, try to par it down and ask a separate question.

Comment: @JosephWright I know. An I probably post it… but in some time, it's a lot to “par down” :)