# Macro parameter delimited by more than one delimiter

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

TeX user can simply create the macro with a parameter delimited by an
arbitrary sequence of tokens. For example

```
\def\macro #1delimiter{...#1...}
```

Is it possible to create a macro with a parameter which has more than one
delimiter? I mean something like this:

```
\mydef\macro #1[first or second]{...#1...}
\macro text first  % -> ...text ... (delimiter is first)
\macro text second % -> ...text ... (delimiter is second)
```

The parameter text should be scanned to the first delimiter from a list of
delimiters. No more scanning. I know that you can set a fixed delimiter
after this (\par for example) and then to treat with this longer parameter
and read words "first" or "second" from it. But this approach reads more
input data than we need. Unwanted tokenization is done, maybe here is
unbalanced text etc.

Comment: You can certainly pick up such delimiters, but not using a single macro. Are we to assume that the following text must be `first` if it starts `f` and `second` if it starts `s`, or is the situation more complex than that?

Comment: @JosephWright My question concerns to the situation most general if it is possible. No spaces are supposed around delimiter, the letters `f` and `s` are only example. And the balanced text is supposed, of course. This is similar to the case when the parameter is delimited by a single delimiter and it have to be balanced too.

Comment: @nov222 Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please, could you tell us what do you need it for?

Comment: @tohecz Welcome too. I need to know if there exists a generalized case for delimited parameters given by \def. For example \macro text-to-the-first-coma-or-space-or-dot. Else \another text-to-the-first "and" or "And" or "AND". Etc.

Comment: The short answer is no, but the longer answer is that it is possible to parse the input stream token by token and build up the potential delimiters letter by letter checking at each stage if the letters so far are an initial substring of each possible delimiter, if you _really_ want to do that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. The question is, how complicated it is. It seems to me usable. Maybe such macro was already done by somebody...

Comment: @nov222 A recent question of min has some sort of “parsing token by token”, however the delimiter is a single token only, not a string. So it would be possible to add to that solution a checking for a string…

Comment: It would be very complicated even just for the special case of testing for `first` and `second` . To implement a system taking an arbitrary list of possible delimiters would be vastly more complicated: certainly hundreds, probably thousands of lines of code I'd guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use my macro `\seplist` exactly for purposes described in your
question. The macro `\seplist` has the following syntax:

```
\def\yourmacro#1{... macro with normal #1 without separator}
\seplist{list of separators}\yourmacro parameter text
```

For example:

```
\def\macro#1{parameter is: "#1"}
\def\separed{\seplist{{sepA}{SepB}{SEPC}}}

\separed\macro text separated by sepA % sepA is separator
\separed\macro text separated by SepB % SepB is separator
\separed\macro text separated by SEPC % SEPC is separator
```

The actually used separator is stored globaly to the `\sepused` macro. The
macro-programmer can use this.

The input stream is read to the first instance of any of the listed
separator, no more. The separator list includes separators in braces.
If there are only one-token separators, braces can be omited. Example:

```
\seplist{0123456789}\macro text to the first decimal digit 7
```

The separators can consist from any tokens except `{` `}` and `#` (more
exactly the categories of these characters play the role). This is the same
as when `\def` primitive with single separator is used. The parameter text
can include these characters, but it have to be always balanced. Thus, the
separator hidden in braces is ignored. This behavior is similar like in
normal separated parameters. Example:

```
\seplist{0123456789}\macro this text {1234} is separated by five: 5
\seplist{\undefined \defined}\macro this text ends by \undefined or \defined
\seplist{{\undefined\defined}\par}\macro this text ends by \undefined\defined or by \par
```

If there are more separators, they all match the same text then the longer
separator wins. Example:

```
\def\m#1{\message{param: "#1", separator: "\sepused"}}
\seplist{{BC}{ABC}}\m ahaABC % -> param: "aha", separator: "ABC"
```

If your `\macro` is defined as `\long` then `\par` can be scanned into parameter.
Warning: if your `\macro` isn't defined as `\long` then parameter scanning doesn't
stop at `\par`! You have to add the `\par` to the separator list. Example:

```
\def\parinmacro{\par}
\def\thismacro{\ifx\sepused\parinmacro \message{something wrong}\fi ...}
\seplist{{ab}{cd}\par}\thismacro This text skips the hidden {ab} and {cd}
                                 and it stops at the end of the paragraph.
```

You can define the `\sepdef` macro with the syntax similar to your
requirement:

```
\def\sepdef #1#2[#3]{\def#1{\seplist{#3}{\csname.\string#1\endcsname}}%
  \long\expandafter\def\csname.\string#1\endcsname ##1}

\sepdef\test #1[{first}{second}]{Parameter is: "#1", separator is "\sepused".}

\test text separated by first
\test text separated by second
```

The implementation of `\seplist` macro follows. It uses only primitives and
basic macros. It should be used in any TeX format.

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\newtoks\seplistT

\long\def\seplistD#1{%
   \seplistS##2\seplistE{\def\tmpa{##1}\def\tmpb{##2}\seplistE}%
   \def\tmpb{\tmpa #1}\expandafter\tmpb \tmp\seplistD\seplistE
}
\long\def\seplistE#1{%
   \ifx\tmpa\empty
      \seplistS\seplistD{\def\tmpb{##1}}\expandafter\tmpa\tmpb
      \ifx\tmpb\empty \seplistQ{#1}%
      \else \expandafter\addto\expandafter\seplistLx
                           \expandafter {\expandafter\seplistD\expandafter{\tmpb}{#1}}%
   \fi\fi
}
\def\seplistS{\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\tmpa\expandafter##\expandafter1\tmp}
\long\def\seplistQ#1#2\seplistA{\fi\fi\gdef\sepused{#1}\seplistZ}

\long\def\seplist#1#2{\begingroup
  \toks0={#2}\let\bgroup=\relax \let\egroup=\relax
  \def\seplistL{}\def\seplistLx{}\seplistI#1{}\gdef\sepused{}%
  \ifx\seplistL\empty \expandafter\endgroup \the\toks0\else
  \seplistT={}\expandafter\seplistA\fi
}
\def\seplistA{\futurelet\tmp\seplistB}
\def\seplistB{\let\next=\seplistP
   \expandafter\ifx\space\tmp \let\next=\seplistC \let\nexxt=\seplistM \fi
   \ifx##\tmp \let\next=\seplistC \let\nexxt=\seplistH \fi
   \ifx{\tmp  \let\next=\seplistG \fi
   \ifx}\tmp  \let\next=\seplistC \let\nexxt=\seplistF \fi
   \next
}
\def\seplistC{\afterassignment\nexxt \let\next= }
\long\def\seplistP#1{\seplistX#1\def\tmp{#1}\seplistN}
\def\seplistM{\seplistX{ }\def\tmp{ }\seplistN}
\def\seplistH{\seplistX{##}\def\seplistLx{}\seplistA}
\def\seplistN{\edef\seplistLx{\expandafter}\seplistLx \seplistL \seplistA}
\long\def\seplistG#1{\def\seplistLx{}\seplistX{{#1}}\seplistA}
\def\seplistF{\seplistT\expandafter{\expandafter{\the\seplistT}}\seplistZ}
\long\def\seplistX#1{\seplistT\expandafter{\the\seplistT#1}}
\def\seplistZ{\let\tmp=\sepused 
   \expandafter\seplistS\expandafter{\the\toks0{##1}}%
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\tmpa\the\seplistT
}
\long\def\seplistI#1{\ifx\seplistI#1\seplistI\else
   \addto\seplistL{\seplistD{#1}{#1}}\expandafter\seplistI \fi
}
```

**Comments to the implementation**

We read the parameter token-per-token similarly as the solution of [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196776/arguments-possibly-delimited-by-bgroup-and-egroup) and store these tokens in `\seplistT` token list. The internal
macro `\seplistL` includes the list of separators in the form:

```
\seplistD{sepA}{sepA}\seplistD{sepB}{sepB}\seplistD{sepC}{sepC}...
```

We store the already read token to `\tmp` and run `\seplistL`. More exactly: at
the start, the temporary `\seplistLx` is emty. For each read token, we expand
`\seplistLx` and `\seplistL` to the input stream and before executing it we
reset `\def\seplistLx{}`. Now, the input stream is executed, i.e. the
`\seplistD` macro is processed for each separator. The task of
`\seplistD{sepA}{sepA}` is the following: to test if the `\tmp` is equal to the
first token of its first parameter (`s` in this example). If it is true,
then `\seplistD` (using `\seplistE`) adds the text `\seplistD{epA}{sepA}` (the
first token from the first parameter is removed) to the temporary list
`\seplistLx` which will be executed for the next token. If `\tmp` isn't equal to
the first token of the first parameter then `\seplistD` does nothing.

For example, the next read token in `\tmp` is `e`. Then `\seplistD{epA}{sepA}`
saves the `\seplistD{pA}{sepA}` to the `\seplistLx`, because the first letter
is `e`. If the next token in `\tmp` is `p`, then `\seplistD{A}{sepA}` is stored
to the `\seplistLx`. And finally, if the next token in `\tmp` is `A`, then
`\seplistD{A}{sepA}` does not store `\seplistD{}{sepA}`, but it decides that
separator is found because the first parameter is empty. It defines `\sepused`
as its second parameter (`sepA`) and it does the end of this game by `\seplistQ`
plus `\seplistZ`. If the last token in `\tmp` isn't `A` then the `\seplistD{A}{sepA}` does nothing and the chain is broken because the `\seplistLx` is set to empty in each step. The new chain can be built because `\seplistD{sepA}{sepA}` is still included in `\seplistL` which isn't changed during calculation.

Macro-programing in TeX is beautiful but it is different than the classical
technique used by "normal" programming. We utilize here the fact that the code can create the code, i.e. data and code isn't strictly separed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : "To implement a system taking an arbitrary list of possible delimiters would
be vastly more complicated: certainly hundreds, probably thousands of lines
of code I'd guess." ... You can compare your guess with the reality: 50 lines of code.

Comment: +1 yes well I suppose hundreds would have been my guess "thousands" was a bit of hyperbole to stress to the user that it wouldn't be just a simple change like using `xdef` instead of `\def`. 50 isn't hundreds either but then you've done this kind of macro programming before:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "you've done this kind of macro programming before" ... yes, I've done the reading token-per-token before. But the separators calculation was my reaction to this thread. It was an example of a subtle modification of my previous code.

Comment: @wipet thank you for this fantastic tool, have you released it somewhere? (I'm mostly asking because I'd like to acknowledge it properly and use correct compatible license in my own project). Perhaps more importantly for my own application: is there any way to add \end{document} as one of delimiters?