# Typesetting hashtags with natural syntax

Tags: macros, environments, catcodes

I'm using an online conversation in my document and I've made an environment to use for it.  The thing is, there are *many* #hashtags in each post (that I'd like to color appropriately).  To make it more readable, I want to make `#` an active character and take everything from the usage to either the next hash (`#`) or a space.

> Help me, I'm #lost.
>
> Help me, I'm #lost!
>
> Best ever #tex #latex #plain_text
>
> What?  #confused#lost#savingspace

I suppose a regular expression that would match a hashtag could be as simple as `#[\-_A-Za-z]`, so the complement would denote a break.

The 'either-or' aspect as too much to get my head around when trying to figure this out, but that's the ideal.  I just decided to make `#` active.  But when you think about it, there's no way you can have a macro argument for this.  You don't have any characters with the appropriate catcode (6).  So, use a different character, right?  Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\maketag[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\##1}}
\newenvironment{post}[2]{%
  #1 said on #2:\quote
  \catcode`"=6
  \catcode`\#=13
  \def\#""1 {\maketag{""1}}%
}{%
  \catcode`"=12 % edit: wasn't needed at all..
  \catcode`\#=6 % #late_night_mistakes
  \endquote
}
\begin{post}{Sean Allred}{yesterday}
  #hello
\end{post}
\end{document}
```

> ```
> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> l.16       #
>             hello
> --- HELP ---
> TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
> name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
> the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
> can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
> environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
> command.
> ```

How can I get the behavior I want?

I'm more than open to `expl3` answers :)

Comment: You may want to take a look at wipet's answers, which do some token swallowing and checking with each token.

Comment: Thanks. (Link for the lazy: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/51799/wipet)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\def\hashtag{%
\textcolor{cyan}{\#}%
\begingroup
\color{red}%
\xhashtag}

\def\xhashtag{\futurelet\tmp\xxhashtag}

\def\xyhashtag#1{\xhashtag}

\def\xxhashtag{%
\ifcat a\noexpand\tmp 
 \tmp\expandafter\xyhashtag
\else
  \endgroup
\fi}

\newenvironment{post}[2]{%
  #1 said on #2:\quote
  \catcode`\#\active
  \catcode`\-11 %
  \catcode`\_11 %
  \lccode`\~`\#%
  \lowercase{\let~}\hashtag
}{%
  \endquote
}
\begin{post}{Sean Allred}{yesterday}
Help me, I'm #lost.

Help me, I'm #lost!

Best ever #tex #latex #plain_text

What? #confused#lost#saving-space
\end{post}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! I don't have a TeX environment to test with, but I from what I understand from reading the code (it's a little bit, ehhh....advanced `;)`), this solution would handle `This is a #test hashtag` => `This is a \magic{#test} hashtag`, yes?

Comment: @SeanAllred probably:-)

Answer (score 20):

There are at least a couple of ways you could do this: catcode changes or the `\lowercase` 'trick'. As you've started off with catcodes, I'll stick with that. What you need to remember is you are tokenizing material when you do `\newenviroment`. As such, you need to change catcodes *before* the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\maketag[1]{\##1}
\catcode`\"=6 %
\catcode`\#=\active
\newenvironment{post}{%
  \def#""1 {\maketag{""1}}%
  \catcode`\#=\active
  \quote
}{%
  \endquote
}
\catcode`\"=12 %
\catcode`\#=6 %

\begin{document}
\begin{post}
  #hello
\end{post}
\end{document}
```

Notice that inside the environment we only need to change the catcode of `"`: we need the *definition* to have `"` as the parameter char, but not to *read* the environment. It's only `#` that has special handling here. Also notice that as environments form groups there is no need to worry about resetting catcodes in the `\endpost` macro (end-of-environment argument).

For contrast, the `\lowercase` approach would look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\maketag[1]{\##1}
\newenvironment{post}{%
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=\#
    \lowercase{%
      \endgroup
      \def~##1}{\maketag{##1}}%
  \catcode`\#=\active
  \quote
}{%
  \endquote
}

\begin{document}
\begin{post}
  #hello
\end{post}
\end{document}
```

Here, I don't have to mess with catcodes beyond making `#` active inside the environment. The idea here is that `~` is active anyway, so I can lower-case it into a `#` (which remains active) while using  a 'normal' `#` for setting up the definition.

By the way, notice that in both cases we need to double the parameter char here as `#1` (standard catcodes) refers to any argument for the environment itself. I didn't understand why you'd got `[2]` for arguments to that, so I dropped it!

Comment: You could of course simply use a verbatim environment: I'm guessing that's not what you are after!

Comment: Is it possible to define `\makehashtagon` (like `\makeatletter`) and define `\newenvironment{post}{\makehashtagon}{\makehashtagoff}`?

Comment: @Symbol1 It's of course a bit more complex as `\makeatletter` only alters the catcode of `@` but as it's not active there is no definition. You could wrap up either version of the above, with the result that `#` would grab an argument and apply `\maketag`, for example. As with the above, you wouldn't need `\makehashtagoff` as the environment forms a group.

Comment: Forget `\makehashtagoff` :P I realize that I have to change catcode of `#` *before* I define `\makeatletter`, right?

Comment: @Symbol1 ask a new linked question: I can show the idea but doesn't quite make sense as an edit here!

Comment: [Here you are](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201607/define-a-macro-changing-category-code-of-number-sign-namely-makenumbersignlett)

Comment: You forgot a third way: `\let#\maketag` would avoid the acrobatics with ``\catcode`\"=6`` in the first solution (and would shorten the second one).

Comment: The `[2]` arguments were leftover cruft… I wasn't quite in my right mind at 1am last night! :)

Comment: Also note that there a couple of use cases (which I very helpfully neglected to include last night) that aren't covered.  See a a forthcoming edit.

Comment: @egreg As in your other comment, I think that depends on the semantics here: is `#` an interface which should be equivalent to `\maketag` or one that passes data _to_ `\maketag`.

Answer (score 10):

Customizable at will (but of course rather slow):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,environ,xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{post}{mm}
 {
  \char_set_catcode_other:N \# % change the catcode not to confuse \innerpost
  \char_set_catcode_other:N \_
  #1~said~on~#2\tl_to_str:n {:}\quote
  \innerpost % absorb the contents
 }
 {
  \endinnerpost\endquote
 }
\NewEnviron{innerpost}
 {
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \#([[:word:]\-]*) }
   { \c{texttt}\cB\{\c{coloredhash}\1\cE\} }
   \BODY

  \BODY
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\coloredhash{\textcolor{cyan}{\#}}

\begin{document}

\begin{post}{Sean Allred}{yesterday}
Help me, I'm #lost.

Help me, I'm #lost!

Best ever #tex #latex #plain_text

What? #confused#lost#saving-space
\end{post}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An example of further customization, suppose you want to accept accented characters in the hashtags, with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`; it's sufficient to change the search regular expression into

```
{ \#((\c[LA][^\~]|\_|\-)*) }
```

which matches any combination of letters, active characters (except for ~), the hyphen and the underscore.

A solution based on `\ifcat` would need much more tests.

Comment: A doubt, what does `[[:word:]]` do? Is it the same as `\w`?

Comment: @Manuel I think it's the same, but clearer: letters, digits and underscore.

Answer (score 7):

There are two problems here. The catcode changing (which was solved in previous answers) and your wish that the argument of hash ends by "space OR hash". Your example:

```
What? #confused#lost#savingspace
```

I guess that this second problem isn't solved in previous answers. It could be solved in general, see [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200452/macro-parameter-delimited-by-more-than-one-delimiter). But we needn't so complicated code in this special case. We suppose, that the space definitely occurs after the sequence of `#aa#bb#cc#etc`. The whole sequence would be the argument of the first hash. We need to deactivate the internal hashes in such parameter only.

Now, the implementation:

```
\def\sethash#1{\lccode`\~=`\#\lowercase{\let~=#1}}
\def\maketag#1 {{\color{cyan}\sethash\#\##1}} % macro parameter separated by space

\newenvironment{post}{%
     \sethash\maketag \catcode`\#=\active     
  \quote
}{%
  \endquote
}
```

I hope, you can add another LaTeX specific code (like `\documentclass` etc).

Comment: I wouldn't leave the `\lccode` setting for `~` in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

This short code sets “#” active inside the environment, and defines `#` to be (in this case) equal to `\#` (chek the handy functions `\char_set_active:Npn` or `\char_set_eq:NN`).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { post } { }
  { \quote \char_set_active_eq:NN \# \# }
  { \endquote }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{post}
  #hello
\end{post}
\end{document}
```

Now the deeper question on how to handle the “arguments”. One option was swallowing tokens until finding a non-letter (finally answered by David). The other option was `l3regex` (egreg made a similar approach). In this case, since `_` is non-letter (subscript), this doesn't handle `#something_like_this`, but you can change the catcode whenever you want.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{environ,l3regex,xparse,xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron { post }
  {
   \tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl { \BODY }
   \regex_replace_all:nnN
    { (\#)([\w\-]+) } { \c{textcolor}\cB\{cyan\cE\}\cB\{\c{\#}\2\cE\} }
    \l_tmpa_tl
   \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{post}
  #hello #ratata And not a hashtag, and a
  #hashtag#another#another with #hyphens-but
  (\string_ doesn't work)
\end{post}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the cleanest solution.  `\maketag` can be easily defined with `u{~}` as the argspec (if you disregard the alternate `#/~` requirement) :)

Comment: I think `[A-Za-z_]*` is the actual regex for most applications, so the complement would indicate a break.

Comment: Well yes, I'm making certain assumptions to avoid the recursion, but I think there is a way (at least in e-TeX) to scan ahead *looking* for a token (potentially a group of tokens), so there might be an `expl3` analog.  You could then have something like `\NewDocumentCommand\maketag{m}{…}\cs_new:Npn\hashtags_scan_and_make:{…\maketag{…}}`

Comment: @SeanAllred Sorry, I don't understand :(

Comment: See the edit to my comment.  I'll try to figure a solution during lunch today and edit your post if that's okay with you :).

Comment: Still lost. You are looking for a solution in the definition of `\maketag`, aren't you? Then I think `u{~}` wouldn't work, since you may end with other symbols “inside the hashtag” (like `.` or `,`). And, after that… I don't know where you are going! Feel free to edit :)

Comment: `{u{~}}` was an off-hand suggestion for something that would work as well as the higher-voted answer (which actually doesn't do argument-grabbing appropriately).  Of course, the wouldn't be appropriate for a more robust solution.

Comment: @SeanAllred I'm going to try with `l3regex`.

Answer (score -1):

simply using the backslash, the hash sign, and the word in curly brackets worked for me:

```
\#{MeToo}
```

produced

> #MeToo

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to the site :-) This is the trivial approach and does work, but note though that in my original question, "I want to make `#` an active character and take everything from the usage to either the next hash (`#`) or a space."

Comment: I'll note that the braces should be unnecessary. You *may* need to have a space like so: `\# MeToo` given TeX's tokenization rules. Brackets effectively do the same thing, but look a little awkward to my biased eyes.