# Define a macro changing category code of number sign (namely \makenumbersignletter)

Tags: macros, catcodes

Under [Typesetting hashtags with natural syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201591/typesetting-hashtags-with-natural-syntax/201598?noredirect=1#comment469566_201598) Joseph Wrigh ask me to ask a new question:

In LaTeX, `\makeatletter` is short for changing the category code of `@`. But something like

```
\def\makenumbersignletter{\catcode`#=11}
```

gives error. What should I do?

Here is the non-working example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \def\makenumbersignletter{\catcode`#=11}
\end{document}
```

### More Question

Based on Joseph's answer, the safest way is

```
\catcode`\#=11\relax
```

Then it comes into my mind why TeX accepts the *unsafe* way `\catcode｀@11`? And what should `\catcode｀\=11` be: is it `\catcode｀\\=11` or `\catcode｀\==11`? Same problem appears between `\let\a\b` and `\let\a=\b`. The worst thing is that `｀` and `=` do not have a specific category code, what if one day I need `\makegraveletter` or `\makeequalsignletter`?

Comment: I'm asking what's the use of `#` with category code 11. If any, it should be 12. The category code of `\`` and `=` is normally 12 (and this category code is *required* in the syntax of assignments and alphabetic constants).

Comment: @egerg I just wonder where is the limit. I am not going to play with it in any serious document. (But 12 is required for csname such as `\parameter#xxiv`, is it reasonable?)

Comment: No; catcode 12 is not needed if you use `\csname a#b\endcsname` (unless it's in the replacement text for `\def`, where you need `##`).

Comment: @egreg Codes combining `\csname`, `\string`,  `\expandafter`, and so and so always drive me crazy. I think I should stop here since I can use fullwidth characters in Unicode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer here is that you need to escape `#` and use `\#`: some chars are not 'safe' on their own but the escaped versions always are. A classic example is `%`, which would start a comment normally but doesn't when you use `\%`. As [David says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201608), TeX *always* allows the use of single-character commands as part of the backtick syntax in contexts such as `\catcode, so it's always safe to use the escaped version even if not needed.

Taking that knowledge and using the example from the linked question to make a few different possibilities we might end up with something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\makehashletter{\catcode`\#=11 }
\newcommand*\makehashparameter{\catcode`\#=6 }
\newcommand*\makehashtag{%
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\~=\#
  \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
    \def~##1}{\maketag{##1}}%
  \catcode`\#=\active
}
\newcommand\maketag[1]{\##1}
\begin{document}
\makehashletter
#
\makehashtag
#text
\makehashparameter
\end{document}
```

Notice that I've added a space after the catcodes in both of the cases here: this stops TeX looking for more digits and is best practice when creating such commands. (I could use a `\relax` here.)

Comment: ``\begingroup\lccode`~=`#\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\maketag`` is much easier

Comment: @egreg Depends what exactly you want to achieve (if `\maketag` changes should `#` or not).

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
`\#
```

The backtick notation takes a single character or a single character control token, for this reason.